# Angular is not allowing me do the integar comparison if value is type casted in string in controller. Please have a look at this code snippet

Tags: angularjs

When i add dynamic text box and compare this value to orignal prize than the result are untrue. try to add a text box and insert 111 for instance.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="nCtrl">

  <h1>{{challenge.prize}}</h1>

  <a ng-click="addBoxes()"> Add Box </a>

  <div ng-repeat="data in challenge.boxes track by $index">
    why its not working  right {{challenge.boxes[$index].prize > challenge.prize}}
    <input type="text" ng-model="challenge.boxes[$index].prize">

  </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('nCtrl', function ($scope) {
      $scope.challenge = {
        prize: '12',
        boxes: []
      };

      $scope.addBoxes = function () {
        $scope.challenge.boxes.push({prize: ''})
      };

    });
  </script>

  <p>The prize is written as a string, but formatted as a number.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you change `$scope.challenge = {
        prize: 12,
        boxes: []
      };` to this ?

Comment: Because i have to construct an empty object with no prize so user can manually input value for  challenge.prize through text box.

Comment: Then keep it an integer, string will create problem or you can parse it to integer.

Answer (score 3):

Set input type number in your html and it working fine.

Or use custom filter in place of angular number filter

```
app.filter('num', function() {
    return function(input) {
      return parseFloat(input, 10);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have change the value of prize string to int,then getting correct output as mention below :

```
$scope.challenge = {
  prize: 12,
  boxes: []
};
```

see demo on fiddler [link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/HimanshuSharma/ekorrqvt/5/)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="nCtrl">

  <h1>{{challenge.prize}}</h1>

  <a ng-click="addBoxes()"> Click here to Add Box </a>
  </br>
  </br>
  <div>
    Now Its Working...
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="data in challenge.boxes track by $index">
    Conditional based Output :<strong> {{challenge.boxes[$index].prize > challenge.prize}} </strong>
    <input type="text" ng-model="challenge.boxes[$index].prize">

  </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('nCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.challenge = {
        prize: 12,
        boxes: []
      };

      $scope.addBoxes = function() {
        $scope.challenge.boxes.push({
          prize: ''
        })
        console.log($scope.challenge.boxes)
      };

    });
  </script>

  <p>The prize is written as a string, but formatted as a number.</p>
```

Comment: Hello Himanshu i appreciate your efforts. I am aware of that if we write an integer value for the model it will work. The problem is challenge.prize is not static. This value is also pulled from a text box. The  issue is about the type casting of value. In our case i purposely challenge.prize to string.

Comment: And even angular number filter did not help.